# Docker GitHub Automated Build Arguments

Tags: docker, github, build

I'd like to set build arguments for my automated build:

https://hub.docker.com/r/mastermindg/jenkins-mesos/

This is being fed from:

https://github.com/mastermindg/jenkins-mesos

I can get the tags for the build but I don't see any way to set the build arguments, i.e. BLUEOCEAN_VERSION.

How can I set custom build arguments from Docker Hub for an automated build?

Answer (score 1):

Docker Cloud allows passing Environment Variables to Automated Builds:
[image]

When the build completes in Docker Cloud it is pushed to Docker Hub. For now Docker Cloud is in Beta but has a rich API.